# Setting SSL redirect ONLY for the frontpage on Drupal?

Tags: .htaccess, drupal

I want users that visit my site to be redirected to the SSL version when they access it like this

```
www.mysite.com
```

But when they access other urls, such as...

```
www.mysite.com/some
www.mysite.com/other
www.mysite.com/links
```

That it goes to the normal version.

This is what i have so far that DOESNT work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This does it for ALL pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You current ruleset is only checking the `HTTP_HOST`. To identify requests for your frontpage, you need to add checks for the `REQUEST_URI`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$ [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/node$ [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/yourFrontpageAlias$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This would also check for an empty request URI, for the standard Drupal frontpage 'node' and an alias you might have given it. This is just an untested example. If you've changed your default frontpage, you need to substitute 'node' with that one. Also *make sure to test for trailing slash situations* - depending on your setup, you'd need to allow matching those also.

You should probably also add a check of the `HTTPS` [Server variable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond) and skip the rule, if the request is for https already. It will contain 'on' or 'off' accordingly.

If you want to force other pages to explicit non ssl, you need to add a rule redirecting to non ssl for all other cases as well.

In addition to the standard mod_rewrite documentation page linked above, you might want to check the examples/explanations of the [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

---

Also note that depending on your setup, you might not need/want to check the `HTTP_HOST` at all, e.g. you might have different hosts pointing to your instance (now or in the future - a common example would be 'www.mysite.com', which your current setup would ignore).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Drupal securepages module: http://drupal.org/project/securepages

Cheers